# Exercise: Relation between bounded derivative and limit of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

> Let $\;f(x)={\vert g(x)-l \vert }^2 \;$ where $\;g: (a,b) \rightarrow
>  \mathbb R^n\;$ a Lipschitz continuous map. Note that it holds
>   $\;-\infty \le a \lt 0 \lt b \le \infty\;$ If :
>
> 1. $\; \lim_{x \to b} g(x) = l\;$
> 2. $\;(f^{(2-k)/4})' \le -c \;\;\forall x \in (δ,b)\;$ where $\;0 \lt k \lt 2\;$ and $\;c,δ\;$ some positive constants
>
> Then $\;b \in \mathbb R\;$

My professor told me that the second condition implies $\;b \in \mathbb R\;$ but I'm having a really hard time understanding this. Unfortunately, I can't see the connection between the above conditions.

Any help or hint would be valuable. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you denote $h := f^{(2-k)/4}$, then $h\geq 0$ and, by (1), $\lim_{x\to b} h(x) = 0$. Moreover, due to condition (2), $h$ must be strictly positive for $x < b$, hence it is not difficult to verify that it is locally Lipschitz continuous in $(a,b)$.
On the other hand, from condition (2) we get
$$
0 \leq h(x) \leq h(\delta) - c(x-\delta),\qquad x\in (\delta, b),
$$
so that $x$ cannot exceed $\delta + \frac{h(\delta)}{c}$.

Comment: First of all, I'd like to thank you for your answer. It's a bit unclear to me though, why $\;x\;$ cannot exceed $\;δ+\frac{h(δ)}{c}\;$. Could you explain that to me in more details please? How does this imply $\;b\in \mathbb R\;$?

Comment: Since $0 < h(\delta) - c(x-\delta)$, you get $x < \delta + h(\delta)/c$, hence  $b \leq  \delta + h(\delta)/c$.

Comment: Oh, I see... One last question... Did you mean $\;h\;$ is locally Lipschitz continuous in $\;(δ,b)\;$? Where is this information needed? However ,thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Since $h$ is only a.e. differentiable, in order to integrate the inequality $h'(x) \leq -c$ you need $h$ be absolutely continuous on the interval of integration.

Comment: Oh I missed that. You've been very helpful!